# convert uppercase letter to lowercase letter

Tags: java

Write a program called CaseConverter with a main method that converts a single uppercase letter to a lowercase letter. You have to declare a char variable to hold the lowercase letter.

```
public class CaseConverter {
  public static void main (String [] args){

    int offset = 'a' - 'A';

    char temp = 'X';  // or any other uppercase alphabet
    System.out.println("uppercase: " + temp);

    // insert code here 

    System.out.println("lowercase: " + temp);

  }      
}
```

Comment: i dont understand "offset". how are offset and temp related>

Comment: Somehow I feel that the included code was provided by the teacher.

Comment: Unicode, the character set used by Java, has 1039 uppercase characters, 27 of which do not have corresponding lowercase characters. A key part of programming is avoiding incorrect assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code of Uppercase alphabet 'A' is 67 and Code of Lowercase alphabet is 'a' is 97. So, the offset is 32. So, to convert any Uppercase alphabet to Lowercase alphabet you have to add 32 i.e. offset to it.
Edit:

```
public class CaseConverter{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       int offset = 'a' - 'A';
       int temp = 'X';  // or any other uppercase alphabet
       System.out.println("uppercase: " + (char)temp);
       temp = temp + offset;
       System.out.println("lowercase: " + (char)temp);
    }
}
```

Edit: Since your temp data type is char, then this would work

```
public class CaseConverter{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       int offset = 'a' - 'A';
       char temp = 'X';  // or any other uppercase alphabet
       System.out.println("uppercase: " + temp);
       temp = (char)((int)temp + offset);
       System.out.println("lowercase: " + temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: my temp datatype is char

Answer (score 2):

This can be used for case conersion

```
public char toLowercase(char c) {
    int offset = 'a' - 'A';
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        return (char) (c + offset);
    }
    return c;
}

public char toUppercase(char c) {
    int offset = 'a' - 'A';
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        return (char) (c - offset);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use java Character class static method which convert upper case character to lowercase character :> `Character.toLowerCase(c)`;

Comment: Surprisingly, the result is not necessarily a lowercase letter—even if the input is an uppercase letter! This is a scenario where validation of input needs the candidate output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be easily answered if you look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). When you write `a`, the `int` variable will hold the ASCII value of the character `a`.

Look for example at the ASCII value of the letter `P`, it is 80. How do you get the ASCII value of `p` which is 112? I won't give you full solution but this should help you to begin<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* `'a' - 'A'` is 32</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public CaseConverter{
   public static void main(String args[]){
     char temp = 'X';  // or any other uppercase alphabet
    System.out.println("uppercase: " + temp);
   System.out.println(temp.toUpperCase() );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

offset:
lower case letters in ASCII code follows uppercase by 32 as I can remember so if you have an uppercase letter 'X' the you sub its int value by the difference between upper and lower case letters you get the lower.

> `char ch = 'x'; //x is lower case letter
>   int diff = (int)'a' - (int)'A'; //Difference between lower and upper
>   ch = (int)ch - diff; //now you get the lower case`